# Navigation bar button unable to go back to the previous view

Tags: uibutton, ios7

I have followed the informations that i have found online and I have managed to show the button but when i clicked on it, nothing happens. I am new to iOS programming and I am not sure if I did anything wrong.

```
UIImage *backImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"backIcon.PNG"];
// create the button and assign the image to the button
UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[backButton setImage:backImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
backButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, backImage.size.width, backImage.size.height);

[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(goBack:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *customBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBarButton;
```

and this code for the button

```
- (void)goBack:(id)sender {
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; }
```

Thanks

Comment: If you put a break point in `goBack:` function, does it stop there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you don't have to hide the back button since you are adding your own, second try to replace your button target with the below:

```
[backButton addTarget:self.navigationController action:@selector(popViewControllerAnimated:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Edit:

The right way to use navigationController in storyboard will be as following:

1- Add a UInavigationController.

2- Add `rootViewController` relation to first VC1.

3- Add `push` segue from VC1 to VC2.

By this you can push and pop your VC2 properly.

Please consider to read [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1) tutorial for better understanding storyboard, segues and navigation.

Comment: I have followed your advice and changed the button target but when I click on the button, it does not bring me back to the previous view..

Comment: hmm, how do you initialize your ViewController? are you adding it to the UINavigationController properly? please consider to mention you app structure briefly.

Comment: I embed the second view to the navigation controller and use the modal sague to link the first view to the second view's navigation controller

Comment: Nooo, both VC's should be in the same navigation controller. I will update the answer and explain the right way to do navigation for you.

Comment: ahh awesome! It worked but then i did a slide out menu and the menu covered the view.. Any idea if i can use modal instead of push segue??

Comment: Yes you can, you can change the segue to VC2 to be modal and then you put a dismiss button to it.